# How to execute @Sql before a @Before method

Tags: spring, spring-test

I'm trying to combine the follow annotations:

- `org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql`
- `org.junit.Before`

Like the follow code:

```
@Test
@Sql(scripts = "dml-parametro.sql")
public void testData(){
    Iterable<Parametro> parametros = parametroService.findAll();
    List<Parametro> parametrosList = Lists.newArrayList(parametros);

    Assert.assertThat(parametrosList.size(), Is.is(1));
}

@Before
public void beforeMethod() {
    JdbcTestUtils.deleteFromTables(jdbcTemplate, "PARAMETRO");
}
```

The code in the method `@Before` is running after than the `dml-parametro.sql` script in the `@Sql` annotation.

Is it right to do this?

For solution this, I'm using `@After` in place than `@Before`, but I'd like to `cdelete` tables before the test execution, not after.

I wouldn't like to use `@SqlConfig`. I'm not using transactional scope on test level, so I need to clean my tables in every test method. If every test method need to clean tables, I would like to do this in `@Before` method. I wouldn't like to do this in every test method with `@SqlConfig`. I think the behavior of `@Sql` to be execute before than `@Before` is wrong.

Answer (score 63):

By default, any SQL scripts executed via `@Sql` will be executed *before* any `@Before` methods. So the behavior you are experiencing is correct, but you can change the execution phase via the `executionPhase` attribute in `@Sql` (see example below).

If you want to execute multiple scripts, that is also possible via `@Sql`.

So if you have a clean-up script named `clean-parametro.sql` that deletes from the `PARAMETRO` table, you could annotate your test method like the following (instead of invoking `JdbcTestUtils.deleteFromTables()` in your `@Before` method).

```
@Test
@Sql({"dml-parametro.sql", "clean-parametro.sql"})
public void test() { /* ... */ }
```

Of course, if `dml-parametro.sql` inserts values into the `PARAMETRO` table, then it likely does not make sense to immediately delete those values in the clean-up script.

Please note that `@Sql` and `@SqlConfig` provide multiple levels of configuration for script execution.

For example, if you want to create tables before your test and clean up after your test, you could do something like this on Java 8:

```
@Test
@Sql("create-tables.sql")
@Sql(scripts = "clean-up.sql", executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
public void test() { /* ... */ }
```

Or use `@SqlGroup` as a container on Java 6 or Java 7:

```
@Test
@SqlGroup({
    @Sql("create-tables.sql"),
    @Sql(scripts = "clean-up.sql", executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
})
public void test() { /* ... */ }
```

If your tests are `@Transactional` and you'd like to clean up committed database state, you can instruct Spring to execute your clean-up SQL script in a new transaction like this:

```
@Test
@Sql("insert-test-data.sql")
@Sql(
  scripts = "clean-up.sql",
  executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD,
  config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = ISOLATED)
)
public void test() { /* ... */ }
```

I hope this clarifies things for you!

Cheers,

Sam *(author of the Spring TestContext Framework)*

---

Notes:

- `AFTER_TEST_METHOD` is statically imported from `ExecutionPhase`
- `ISOLATED` is statically imported from `TransactionMode`

Comment: i have an abstract class annotated with `@Sql` which runs some scripts, and a subclass of it which also is annotated with `@Sql`. when i was running spring boot 1.2 everything worked as expected -> abstract class scripts were run before child class scipts. but once i upgraded to spring boot 1.3, child class `@Sql` started overriding abstract parent class's `@Sql` and thus parent class scripts are never run. i don't know what to do now :/

Comment: I have created a question for this, found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296329/sub-classing-sql-annotated-class