# Merging @Sql from superclass with @Sql in subclass

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot, spring-test

I have an abstract class annotated with `@Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts="someScript")` .

I have a test class which inherits from the abstract class. The child class is also annotated with `@Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts="someOtherScript")`.

When I was running spring boot 1.2, everything worked as I expected it to: scripts from parent class were run before child class. I upgraded to spring boot 1.3 and now, the child class's `@Sql` overrides parent class's `@Sql` and the parent class scripts are never run.

With spring boot 1.3 is there a different way of doing this? So that parent class scripts are run before child class scripts?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that you did not change _any_ of the related code?

Comment: Can you please tell us the exact versions of `spring-test` that you were using _before_ and _after_ you migrated?

Comment: FYI: if you upgraded from Spring Framework 4.1 to Spring Framework 4.2, then the following issue could be the cause of the different behavior: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13068

Comment: Just a friendly note that if you find one of the answers to your question acceptable, feel free to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After @SamBrannen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39307103/5929690), I ended up running the script from child class using `ScriptUtils.execute` method.

Answer (score 6):

> With spring boot 1.3 is there a different way of doing this? So that parent class scripts are run before child class scripts?

OK, after some investigative work, I have come up with an answer to your question.

**Short Answer**

No, what you are attempting to do is unfortunately not possible.

**Detailed Answer**

By design, merging of a local class-level declaration of `@Sql` with a class-level declaration of `@Sql` on a superclass has never been supported. A local declaration was always intended to *override* a declaration on a superclass.

Thus, you were simply lucky (or unlucky, depending on how you see it) that it worked for you at all.

The only reason it ever worked for you was due to a bug in core Spring's support for looking up `@Repeatable` annotations (see [SPR-13068](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13068) for details).

However, this bug was fixed in Spring Framework 4.2, and since Spring Boot 1.3 automatically upgraded your Spring Framework dependencies to 4.2 that's why you noticed the issue after the Spring Boot upgrade.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Rahul Sharma,
here is my implementation in abstract class

```
  @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        try {
            ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript( Objects.requireNonNull(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()).getConnection(), new ClassPathResource("/sql/clean.sql"));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }`
```